Running Unit Tests with Fastlane Failed on Xcode 16
When executing lane to run tests on xcode 16, I am getting below strange error.
Cannot test target “MyTargetTests” on “My Mac”: MyTargetTests does not support My Mac’s platform: com.apple.platform.macosx

How ever, I do not set macOS as deployment target. Also the same test work fine on Xcode 15.3.
My Fastfile as below. Does anyone face similar issue on Xcode 16?
default_platform(:ios)

xcodes(version: "16.0", select_for_current_build_only: true)

run_tests(
        scheme: scheme,
        fail_build: false,
        code_coverage: true,
        output_directory: "test-reports/#{scheme}",
      )


Manage to resolve by specifying the devices in the lane. Might be a temporary fix for now.
run_tests(
        scheme: scheme,
        fail_build: false,
        code_coverage: true,
        output_directory: "test-reports/#{scheme}",
        devices: ["iPhone 15"], # Fix for Xcode 16: Specify the iOS simulator device 
      )

